# ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets not working in jsx files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

The vscode [ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) extension stopped working inside `.jsx` and `.tsx` files.

When I disabled the built-in extension **TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**, the snippets worked as normal.

Is there a fix for this?

I checked the [github repo](https://github.com/ults-io/vscode-react-javascript-snippets) found 1 open issue about this bug.

Adding the link to the issue: [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173244)

Comment: why don't people search SO before asking a question? The third one today with the same issue

Comment: add a link to that issue you found. Is it this? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173244. Try the insiders version, or update us when you get v1.75.1 on whether the issue still reproduces.